# Prolog - aggregate : extract other variable than the minimum

Tags: prolog, swi-prolog

I  would like to know if there is a way to extract the X Value when I'm doing this :

```
aggregate_all(min(V), simulate(P, Color, V, X), Value)
```

The **simulate** predicate is used with **P** and **Color** as inputs and **V** and **X** as outputs.

For now, this works well to get the min value of **V**, but what I actually want is to get the value of **X** when **V** is at its minimum.

Is there a way to do that ? Any idea about how should I proceed ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

aggregate library supports a 'Witness' on min/max scalar aggregates: then this should work

```
aggregate_all(min(V,X), simulate(P, Color, V, X), min(Value,X))
```